# Check if an array is mirrored in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to check if the inputted array of the user is mirrored or not

Users input:

```
//for the rows and column
3 3
//elements inside array
1 0 1
2 0 3
4 0 4
```

the output should tell if the first index and the last index of the array is the same, but the only thing that i have done is mirror it and print mirror even if its not the same

```
int main()
{                       
    int arr[10][10];   
    int col,row;   
 
    scanf("%d %d", &col, &row);    
 
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }       
 
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        for(int j = row - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            printf("Mirror"); 
        }
    }       
}
```

the size of the array and the elements depends on the user, thank youuu

Comment: Hi Qwet, you've shown us some code, but did you have a question?

Comment: i forgot to put it sorry, i wanted to know how can i compare the last index and first index of a 2d array because i want to put mirror if those index are the same and put not if the index are not the same

Comment: Input
5 5
5 4 5
2 1 2
3 3 3
1 1 1

output:
mirror

input
5 5
5 4 5
2 1 2
3 3 3
1 1 9

output:
not

Comment: *the first index and the last index of the array is the same*. Is that really your definition of a mirrored matrix? The comparison is: `arr[0][0] == arr[col-1][row-1]`. But I find that definition odd.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you iterate through the columns of each row, that means that usually `i` (the outer loop) represents the rows and `j` the columns.

This piece of code shows a way to check if a 2D array is mirrored horizontally:

```
int mirror = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    
    for(int j = 0; j < col/2; j++) {
        
        // comparing first element with last element of row `i`
        // than comparing the second element with the second last
        // and so on, till you reach the center of the row, `j==col/2`
        // if the comparison is true just one time, the array is not mirrored
        if( array[i][j] != array[i][col-j-1] ) { 
            
            mirror = 0;
            i = row; // to break the outer loop
            break;
        }                  
    }                                    
}                                                        

mirror ? puts("Mirror!") : puts("No mirror.");
```

At the end of the program if the variable `mirror` still have a value of `1`, you got a mirror array.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error which is going to overflow your array reads.  When writing answers to help a beginner, it's important to check your own code.  Otherwise you will just confuse them even more.

Comment: You are right, he could have written another question to ask why this code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for your problem, this code can have some isuess but in general do what you ask for. Adapt for your particular needs.

**OUTPUT:**

```
This program will check if an array is mirrored. Press enter to proceed!
 
Insert row*col -> 3*3
Insert row 1 elements, one by one!
Element 1 -> 1
Element 2 -> 0
Element 3 -> 1
Insert row 2 elements, one by one!
Element 1 -> 2
Element 2 -> 0
Element 3 -> 3
Insert row 3 elements, one by one!
Element 1 -> 4
Element 2 -> 0 
Element 3 -> 4
Mirror found at row 1!
1 0 1 
Mirror found at row 3!
4 0 4
```

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOLUMN 10
#define MAXROW    10

void clean(){
  int temp;
  while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF);
}

void print(int dim,int r, int row[][MAXCOLUMN]){
  for(int index = 0; index < dim; index++)
    printf("%d ",row[r][index]);
  putchar('\n');
}

int main(void){
  int arr[MAXROW][MAXCOLUMN];
  int col,row,mirror;

  puts("This program will check if an array is mirrored. Press enter to proceed!");

  do{
    clean();
    printf("Insert row*col -> ");
  } 
  while(scanf("%d*%d", &row, &col)!=2);

  for(int r = 0; r < row; r++){
    printf("Insert row %d elements, one by one!\n",r+1);
    for(int c = 0; c < col; c++){
      do{
        clean();
        printf("Element %d -> ", c+1);
      }while(!scanf("%d",&arr[r][c]));
    }
  }

  for(int r = 0; r < row; r++){
    mirror = 1;
    for(int cFH = 0, cSH = col-1; cFH < col/2; cFH++, cSH--)//cFH -> column index first half | cSH -> column index second half
      if(arr[r][cFH] != arr[r][cSH]){
        mirror = 0;
        break;
      }
    if(mirror){
      printf("Mirror found at row %d!\n",r+1);
      print(col,r,arr);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should they have to adapt this code-dump to suit their needs?  You say it might have issues -- what issues?  Why can't _you_ adapt the way you answer questions by providing a simple, clear answer that addresses the question, explains how to solve the specific part they need, and avoids cluttering code examples with pointless output or introducing a bunch of syntax the OP might not be familiar with.

Comment: true, i'm a newbie and this is the way i found to help, if it's confunding more than helps i'll delete my answer

Comment: Put it this way: imagine that you have written some code and you need a bit of help to figure out one small part of it.  You ask a question about that bit, and someone writes a completely new program for you.  It has different variable names, different input syntax, different output, it uses functions, macros, comma operator, a do-while loop, and several other standard library calls not in the original code...  Now, I've never met a beginner who is good at reading through someone else's code and understanding it, let alone their own.  Don't delete your answer, but I hope you get my point.

Comment: Yeah, i got your point and agree with that, looking better i went too far, i'll have this in consideration on my next answers here, as i say i'm a beginner too, not fully but still... So i hope there is not big isuess on my code, i tried to do my best